# How to correctly install rpy2 in python?

Tags: python, r, rpy2

There are a lot of other questions like mine but they're quite outdated so I think a new updated guide would be helpful for everyone trying to install rpy2 in Python.
In my case, I'm trying to work with the package pymer4 but i couldn't manage to correctly import it.
I found out that the error lies in rpy2.robjects so I decided to follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61622624/how-to-correctly-set-up-rpy2) to create a clean environment

**Steps**

1. I created a new conda environment

   `conda create -n rpy2_env r-essentials<4.2 r-base<4.2 python=3.7`

I set the version to <4.2 because I read online this problem can be caused by a wrong r version. Anyway neither 4.2 nor 4.1 worked for me.

2. I installed the pymer4 package (and its dependecies, including rpy2)
   `conda install -c ejolly -c conda-forge pymer4`
3. I downgraded rpy2 to 3.4.5 (see related question below, I also tried without downgrading)
   `conda install rpy2=3.4.5`
4. When i try to import pymer4 or rpy2.robjects the following error shows up

   `R[write to console]: Error in gettext(fmt, domain = domain, trim = trim) :`
   `3 arguments passed to .Internal(gettext) which requires 2`

In the terminal the logs showed no error during download and installation.
If you need more info about my system or anything else, comment and I will update the question.
I am really stuck at this point, I think i tried everything I could. I would really appreciate if someone could enlighten me.

**Similar Questions**
[Import rpy2 : unable to determine R library path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72321308/import-rpy2-unable-to-determine-r-library-path)
[Rpy2 can't find my R libraries on install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30921570/rpy2-cant-find-my-r-libraries-on-install)
[R[write to console]: Error in gettext(fmt, domain = domain, trim = trim) : 3 arguments passed to .Internal(gettext) which requires 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73319238/rwrite-to-console-error-in-gettextfmt-domain-domain-trim-trim-3-arg)

Comment: Ok thanks, but even if i import rpy2.robjects (without mentioning pymer4) the same error pops up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the solution.
The problem is with `conda` and `rpy2`, apparently `rpy2` installed with `conda` is outdated.

If you want to install `rpy2`, do not use the conda package manager and just use the pip package manager in a new environment (venv or conda env), and everything will work fine. The correct way to install `rpy` thus is:

```
pip install rpy2
```

Be sure not to use `conda install` for other packages in the same environment where you installed `rpy2` with pip to avoid possible conflicts.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Since the stack police won't let me edit the answer I'll just add a comment here. For everyone who is trying to install rpy2: do not use conda package manager and just use the pip package manager and everything will work fine. The correct way to install rpy thus is `pip install rpy2`. Be sure not to use `conda install` for other packages in the same environment where you installed rpy2 with pip to avoid possible conflicts.

Answer (score -2):

#### Problems Installing?

- A few things to check :

  - All prerequisites have been met, such as the right version of R for your platform, and a current release of ArcGIS.
  - Make sure that your user has administrator access, and try running ArcGIS as an Administrator:

  - Start ArcGIS as an administrator, by right clicking the icon, selecting 'Run as Administrator', then trying the script
  - If that doesn't work, the package directory, "arcgisbinding", that gets installed into the R folder (usually, C:\Users<username>\Documents\R\win-library) into the requested place, C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop\Rintegration

  - On Windows 7, [KB2533623](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2533623) must be installed. Without this hotfix, the library will generate the error "The procedure entry point AddDllDirectory could be located".
- The release can be manually installed into R, as shown in [this screencast](https://4326.us/R/zipinst/r%20bridge%20install%20from%20zip_player.html). Use this if you're planning on mostly working from R.
- Still stuck? [Add an issue and we'll take a look](https://github.com/R-ArcGIS/r-bridge-install/issues). ([More about GitHub Issues](https://help.github.com/articles/about-issues/))

Comment: Please do not add duplicate answers, instead update your other answer.

Answer (score -2):

## Install the R-ArcGIS Bridge

Install and update the R-ArcGIS bridge with this Python

### Installation

First, make sure you've installed an appropriate version of R, 3.5 or later.

If you need to install offline, follow the offline installation instructions.

The clip below shows how to download, install and verify proper installation of the bridge:
//github.com/R-ArcGIS/r-bridge-install/blob/master/img/r-install-from-pyt.gif)

#### ArcGIS 10.3.1+

- In the [Catalog window]//desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/map/working-with-arcmap/what-is-the-catalog-window-.htm), navigate to the folder containing the Python Toolbox, `R Integration.pyt`. *Note*: You may have to first add a folder connection to the location that you extracted the files or downloaded via GitHub.
- Open the toolbox, which should look like this:

![//github.com/R-ArcGIS/r-bridge-install/blob/master/img/r-bridge-install-arcmap.png)

- Run the `Install R bindings` script. You can then test that the bridge is able to see your R installation by running the `Print R Version` and `R Installation Details` tools, and running the included [sample tools]//github.com/R-ArcGIS/r-bridge/tree/master/inst/examples).

#### ArcGIS Pro 1.1+

- In the [Project pane]//pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/projects/the-project-pane.htm), either navigate to a folder connection containing the Python toolbox, or right click on *Toolboxes* > *Add Toolbox* and navigate to the location of the Python toolbox.
- Open the toolbox, which should look like this
- Run the `Install R bindings` script. You can then test that the bridge is able to see your R installation by running the `Print R Version` and `R Installation Details` tools, and running the included [sample tools]//github.com/R-ArcGIS/r-bridge/tree/master/src/package/inst/examples).

If everything worked, you should be ready to start! See Next Steps for where to go from here. Remember, you can update the package at any time by running the 'Update R bindings' script.